# How is possible show custom variables in any template using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, continuous-integration

I separated my template by header, menuleft, main page and foother, however in menuleft I need show the name of customer, your license code and other informations that I get from MYSQL and show as a custom variables.

How I can show these custom variables on the menuleft and do it **as automaticatelly** proccess everytime that user navegate by the codeigniter?

Comment: which CI version are u using?

Comment: store this value in session and call into all the page.you can display the value  into the all the page

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I think using the latest stable.

Comment: @Jack you really belive this is a good pratice? I already save 3 informations on sesion.

Answer (score 1):

Create a core controller class called `MY_Controller` if you haven't already done it and make every controller extends this controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function render($view)
    {
        $this->view('layouts/header', $this->data);
        $this->view('layouts/sidebar', $this->data);
        $this->view($view, $this->data);
        $this->view('layouts/footer', $this->data);
    }

}
```

Now in your controller:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // global variables
        $this->data['username'] = 'Álvaro Meireles'; // get it from database or session
        // and so on .. or better move globals to my_controller
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = 'Welcome Home';
        $this->render('welcome_view');
    }

}
```

Comment: Then I need extend from a custom class to a custom controller?

Comment: @ÁlvaroMeireles .. all you controllers will extend `MY_Controller`

Comment: So on your example I will have a base controller, right? @Sherif Salah

Comment: @ÁlvaroMeireles yeah exactly.